# Bluetooth discovery not starting on first click

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-tabs, android-bluetooth

I have few tabs in my activity and one of them is to search for bluetooth devices and display in listview. But I am having strange issue in which when I click on Bluetooth tab first time, it does not start discorvery but when I come back after clicking on any other tab. The search starts and also display the list of bluetooth devices. I could not figure out why it is happening...any help

it is never entering in OnRecieve on first time

Sharing code snippet

```
public class BluetoothSettings extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_settings);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listbt);
    txtgeo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtbt);
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbtBar);
    wait_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_wait_msg);

}
@Override protected void onPause()
{
    bluetooth.cancelDiscovery();
    if(bReceiver != null) {
        bReceiver = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}


@Override protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(setBt != null){
        setBt.clear();
        listview.setAdapter(null);
    }
    bluetooth.enable();
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    wait_msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    bReceiver = new BluetoothReceiver();
    registerReceiver(bReceiver, filter);
    bluetooth.startDiscovery();
    if(!bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
        shouldTurnoffBt = true;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
}

@Override protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}

@Override protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
}

class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "SDSDSSSSSSSSSS ");
        if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "dkidkididididididi #1 ");
            txtgeo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "dkidkididididididi #2 ");
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            setBt.add(new Property(device.getName(), device.getAddress(), rssi));
        }

        if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action))
        {
            BluetoothSettings.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    wait_msg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if(shouldTurnoffBt)
                        bluetooth.disable();
                    if(setBt != null && setBt.size() > 0){
                       Log.d(TAG, "dkidkididididididi #3 ");
                        ArrayList<Property> lt = new ArrayList<Property>(setBt);
                        esWiFiSettings.settingSort(lt);
                        btAdapter = new btAdapter(BluetoothSettings.this, R.layout.bt_adapter, lt, "Bluetooth");
                        listview.setAdapter(btAdapter);
                        bluetooth.cancelDiscovery();
                    } else {
                        txtgeo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtgeo.setText("No Bluetooth Device Found");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
private BluetoothReceiver bReceiver;
public HashSet<Property> setBt = new HashSet<Property>();
String action;
boolean shouldTurnoffBt = false;
ListView listview;
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth;
private TextView txtgeo, wait_msg;
private ProgressBar progress;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess but checking your code and the [BluetoothAdapter JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery()) there is a good chance that your `bluetooth.startDiscovery()` call returns false. From the JavaDoc:

> If Bluetooth state is not STATE_ON, this API will return false. After turning on Bluetooth, wait for ACTION_STATE_CHANGED with STATE_ON to get the updated value.

Check the return value and only start the discovery when you are sure that bluetooth is enabled. If `bluetooth.isEnabled()` returns false, you have to activate bluetooth (like you already do) but you should catch the cited [`ACTION_STATE_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)-Event in your receiver afterwards (and therefore register the receiver before you call `bluetooth.enable()`).

Also, don't forget to call [`unregisterReceiver(bReceiver)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)) in onPause or onStop. If there is more code that you did not show us, the lines

> if(!bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
>           shouldTurnoffBt = true;
>       }

look pretty suspicious regarding your described behaviour ;-)
Be aware that the bluetooth discovery is pretty heavyweight and takes up to 12 seconds.

This BroadcastReceiver things can be tricky. I wrote a wrapper class for [Blaubot](http://blaubot.hgross.eu/) a while ago. Check this code: [BlaubotBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryReceiver](https://github.com/Blaubot/Blaubot/blob/master/blaubot-android/src/main/java/eu/hgross/blaubot/android/bluetooth/BlaubotBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryReceiver.java) (you will also need [this interface](https://github.com/Blaubot/Blaubot/blob/master/blaubot-android/src/main/java/eu/hgross/blaubot/android/bluetooth/IBluetoothDiscoveryListener.java)).
Or if you simply want to connect multiple Android devices, just [use Blaubot](http://blaubot.henning-gross.de/quickstart-android/) with the NFC-Beacon to eliminate the need for the discovery completely.